# Does docker community edition is available for docker version 1.12?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

Two months before i have done a project using docker version 1.12

Now Docker have released CE and EE , now i tried to install docker community Edition of Docker 1.12

i want to test my project in community edition of Docker 1.12

I don't find the version of 1.12 in docker community edition

can someone help me in this? does community edition is available in 1.12 version ?

Comment: Believe that 1.13 is the same as 17.03 CE. No such thing as 1.12 CE. Not sure how much actual functional difference there is between CE and EE though, and CE is basically the open source version anyway, so 1.12 _is_ CE for all intents and purposes, but it's obviously not 1.13.

Comment: Thanks for the info @johnharris85 . i want to install docker-ce which matches docker 1.12 version . "sudo apt-get install docker-ce" this command is to install the latest version of docker-ce right ?. which will point to 1.12 ? if not please let me know how to install the docker-ce by specifying the version i need

Comment: 1.12 CE doesn't exist. See BMitch's answer which is basically the same as my comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker 17.03 community edition (CE) is a rebranding of the open source docker engine after 1.13. Docker 17.03 enterprise edition (EE) is a rebranding of the commercial support docker engine (CS). There's no specific 1.12 community edition, just the original docker-engine 1.12, since that pre-dates the rebranding, but the docker-engine 1.12 is effectively the same thing.